# API funtion using RxSwift

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift

I want to change the API request code written using the closure to RxSwift. 
For example, I would like to make rxGetList() function using getList() function.

```
// This function cannot be modified.
func getList(success: @escaping ([String]) -> Void,
             failure: @escaping (Error) -> Void) {
    // Request to Server...
}

func rxGetList() -> Observable<String> {
    // Using getList() function
    // TODO
}
```

What code should I write in TODO section?
Please give me some advice.

Comment: this `@escaping ([String]) -> Void` is array

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to meet your expectations is to use something like this:

```swift
func rxGetList() -> Observable<String> {
        return Observable.create { observer in
            
            getList(success: { result in
                for everyString in result {
                    observer.onNext(everyString)
                }
                observer.onCompleted()
            }, failure: { error in
                observer.onError(error)
            })
            
            return Disposables.create() {
                // specify any action to be performed on observable dispose (like cancel URL task)
            }
        }
    }
```

Note that you have `[String]` specified as an input type of your `success` closure. If it's not a typo then above code fits. If you want one `String` instead, it's as simple as this:

```swift
func rxGetList() -> Observable<String> {
        return Observable.create { observer in
            
            getList(success: { result in
                observer.onNext(result)
                observer.onCompleted()
            }, failure: { error in
                observer.onError(error)
            })
            
            return Disposables.create() {
                // specify any action to be performed on observable dispose (like cancel URL task)
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You forgot to put the `observer.onCompleted()` after the for loop, but otherwise this is the right answer.

Comment: Thanks for this, Daniel, my bad. Fixed it.

Comment: @PetrGrigorev
@DanielT.

Thank you very much for your reply. It was a great help to me.
I have additional questions.

1. Is there any way to use another operator without ```Observable.create()``` ?
2. Is it possible to return ```Single<[String]>``` instead of ```Observable<[String]>``` ?

Comment: 1. As far as I know this is the standard observable initialization procedure. So if you want something different you'll have to rewrite your `getList()` method for example using RxCocoa, which will generate an observable for you. 2. Just give a try changing `Observable<[String]>` to a `Single<String>` and see what happens. I believe this should work. P.S. if the answer was useful please don't forget to mark it as correct. Thanks.

Comment: The `Observable.create` function is for converting a call-back into an Observable. The other ways of creating an observable are mentioned in the documentation: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift/blob/main/Rx.playground/Pages/Creating_and_Subscribing_to_Observables.xcplaygroundpage/Contents.swift

Comment: Lastly, if `getList` really is just a network call, then look at the `URLSession+Rx.swift` file in the RxCocoa library. The conversion has already been done for you.

Answer (score 1):

Petr Grigorev's answer is the correct one, but if you want to have fun with some extreme function composition, here's a more advanced way to handle it:

```
let rxGetList = Observable.create(rx_(getList(success:failure:)))
    .flatMap { Observable.from($0) }

func rx_<A>(_ fn: @escaping (@escaping (A) -> Void, @escaping (Error) -> Void) -> Void) -> (AnyObserver<A>) -> Disposable {
    {
        fn(singleObserve($0), $0.onError)
        return Disposables.create()
    }
}

func singleObserve<A>(_ observer: AnyObserver<A>) -> (A) -> Void {
    {
        observer.onNext($0)
        observer.onCompleted()
    }
}
```

I'm not sure about actually using the above, but if you have a lot of functions that you want to wrap, it may help reduce the amount of code you have to write.

Comment: Some serious gourmet coding here. Will use it on my own. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you. That's a very interesting code. :)